# How to order stacked bar plot x categories by value of one of the fill categories in ggplot2/R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot my data as a stacked bar with 3 levels ("catg"), but I want the categories on the X-axis to appeared in increasing order by their value of the "low" sub-categories,

here is reproductive example:

```
#creating df:
set.seed(33)
df<-data.frame(value=runif(12),
               catg=factor(rep(c("high","medium","low")),
                           levels = c("high","medium","low")),
               var_name=(c(rep("question1",3),rep("question2",3),rep("question3",3),rep("question4",3)))
#plotting
bar_dist<-ggplot(df,aes(x=var_name,
                              y=value, 
                              fill=catg, 
                             label=round(value,2)))

bar_dist+ geom_bar(stat = "identity",
                   position = "dodge", 
                   width = 0.7)+
  coord_flip() +
  xlab("questions")+
  ylab("y")+
  geom_text(size = 4,position=position_dodge(width = 0.7))
```

And here is my current plot:

[image]

so in this case I should have question3 and then 4, 1, and finally 2. 
every help will be appreciate,

Comment: make var_name a factor and set the levels in the order you want. `reorder` can help. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23886472/reorder-data-in-ggplot

Comment: Thanks, if I understand you correctly, you suggest ordering the factor's levels manually to a specific desired order. I would rather find a solution which could be generalized to other situation, is there a way to apply your method in a way that could be also generalized? is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way could be :

```
df$var_name=factor(df$var_name,levels=rev(levels(reorder(df[df$catg=="low",]$var_name,df[df$catg=="low",]$value))))
```

It uses `reorder()` as suggested by Richard Telford to reorder the levels according to `df$value` after filtering `df` to keep only the `"low"`.
`levels()` is used to extract the levels from the previous function.
`rev()` is used to reverse the levels.
`factor()` reassigns the levels to `df$var_name`

or :

```
df$var_name=factor(df$var_name,levels = df[with(df,order(value,decreasing = T)) ,][df[with(df,order(value,decreasing = T)) ,]$catg=="low",]$var_name)
```

It sorts `df` on `df$value` (by decreasing value), filters on `df$catg` for `"low"` and retrieves `df$var_name` which is used as levels in `factor()`.

The same plotting function is then used:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Excelent! I really appreciate this

Answer (score 3):

A solution that doesn't modify the data frame, using `fct_reorder2()` from the `forcats` library:

```
library(forcats)

bar_dist <- ggplot(df,
                   aes(
                     x = fct_reorder2(var_name, catg, value),
                     y = value, fill = catg, 
                     label = round(value, 2)))

bar_dist + geom_bar(stat = "identity",
                   position = "dodge", 
                   width = 0.7) +
  coord_flip() +
  xlab("questions") +
  ylab("y") +
  geom_text(size = 4, position = position_dodge(width = 0.7))
```

[image: Grouped barplot with columns ordered by value of one variable across groups]