# How to make a bar plot whit ggplot2 whit many classes?

Tags: r, database, ggplot2, plot

I have a database about the frequency of natural disasters by disaster type in every year from 1900 to 2018: Drought, Earthquakes, Floods, etc. This data was taken from https://ourworldindata.org/natural-disasters. The right plot is the following:[image]

I want to recreate this plot using R language whit ggplot2 library. I have loaded the database but when I plot it the bars and names are wrong, my code assigns the higher frequency to the disaster type in an alphabetic order instead of the real frequency in the database. My code is the following:

```r
type2 <- read_csv("C:/Users/Alonso/Desktop/Tesis_MGII/Avance_mayo/escrito/natural-disasters-by-type.csv")
total_type2<-data.frame(type2)
attach(type2)
ggplot(type2, aes(x=Year, y=`Number.of.reported.natural.disasters`, fill=Disaster)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+theme_minimal()+scale_x_continuous(name="Year", breaks =c(1900,1910,1920,1930,1940,1950,1960,1970,1980,1990,2000,2010,2018))
```

The plot is:
[image]

As you can see,the plot is not right. Any ideas?. Greetings.

Comment: It's not that the plot isn't right, just that you haven't given any instructions in your code to change the order. The default is alphabetical order. Change the order of factor levels. It's unclear how you want to rank your ordering: highest maximum value? highest mean value? highest value at latest date?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to order stacked bar plot x categories by value of one of the fill categories in ggplot2/R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41423661/how-to-order-stacked-bar-plot-x-categories-by-value-of-one-of-the-fill-categorie)

Answer (score 2):

We can change the factor level of `Entity` based on the number of events using the function `fct_reorder` from the `forcats` package (part of the `tidyverse` package).

```
library(tidyverse)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  # Filter Year >= 1970, Remove Entity is "All natural disasters" or "Impact"
  filter(Year >= 1970, !Entity %in% c("All natural disasters", "Impact")) %>%
  # Change the factor order based on total sum of events
  mutate(Entity = fct_reorder(Entity, 
                              `Number of reported natural disasters (reported disasters)`,
                              .fun = sum))


ggplot(dat2, aes(x = Year, 
                y = `Number of reported natural disasters (reported disasters)`, 
                fill = Entity)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  scale_fill_viridis_d(direction = -1) +
  theme_minimal() + 
  scale_x_continuous(name = "Year", 
                     breaks = c(1970, 1980, 1990, 2000, 2010, 2018))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

your plot is "ok", mostly. the thing is that your categories are sorted alphabetically. you might need to change that in the order you want.
something like:

```
type2$variable.Y <- factor(type2$variable.Y, levels = c("Floods", "Extreme Weather", "label 3", etc))
```

and then, run the plot again.

Comment: i'm not sure what's the name of your `$variable.Y`... that's up to you, buddy.